# How to change the position of the initialized slide in Splidejs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slide, splidejs

I want to change the position of the slides using Splidejs.
what I mean exactly, is the slides I am dealing with are showed by default in the `transform : translateX(0px)` ; [position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd6pM.png)
But instead I want to set this position to `transform: translateX(620px)` as a default position,
I have succeeded doing changing it for instance, but it will keep the 0px as it default value.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
        const listSlide = document.querySelector('.splide__list');
        listSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(620px)';
    }, [])
```

This  code will work only when the slide is paused and not dragged, when it's dragged the `transform` value will set to 0px again.
I want this `620px` to be the default value instead !
I hope you understood my question